# Why are some files in my working directory concatenated with files from different revisions after checking out master branch?

Tags: git, git-checkout

When I used `git checkout master`, the working directory did not contain files from the HEAD commit of master. It contained files from a distant commit, along with some of these files concantenated together.

This is extremely bizarre since the command should make my working directory match HEAD, but it doesn't.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try `git reset --hard && git clean -dfx`. This will make sure you are matching `HEAD` exactly and you don't have any extra files lingering.

Comment: is your local master is upto date with origin/master, if not, do git pull origin master, see the HEAD. If the HEAD is still behind then you do as  @CoryKramer mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening as per the git documentation that says:

```
git checkout <branch>
           To prepare for working on <branch>, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing
           HEAD at the branch. ** Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the
           <branch>. **
```

Pay special attention to the line inside **. You can verify the same by running

> git checkout --help

Comment: So this is why my HEAD commit contains files that are not suppose to be there? I don't really understand

Comment: Before you ran the checkout command, you had some files which are not part of the new checked out branch and git kept them too. If you really want to loose any uncommitted changes and make a fresh checkout, then run 'git reset --hard' before checking out. That will first clean your working directory.